# AVCaptureSession not being identified in xcode 8.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am new to iOS development and am trying to follow this tutorial to try out the new Machine Learning features that apple has to offer!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p6GA8ODlnX0

Unfortunately, 3 minutes into the video when I try to construct an instance using the AVCaptureSession(), xcode gives me an error saying "use of unresolved identifier 'AVCapture'".

I am not sure what it is I am doing incorrectly. I have here shown my code so far and attached a screenshot of my xcode UI.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        //here is where we start up the camera
        let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    }
}
```

Image of the xcode UI when error is shown

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated, and yes I tried cleaning and rebuilding as well as restarting xcode, no luck there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `import AVFoundation` on your class file. Refer this [AVFoundation framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturesession)